# Публикация приложения в AppStore

Tags: ios, appstore

Всем привет, настало время моей первой публикации в AppStore. Появилось несколько вопросов, на которые не смогли ответить обучающие видео.
1) При публикации могу ли я указать имя разработчика или название компании(то что подписано справа) которые не соответсвуют моей имени и фамилии в AppleDev. Если да, то будут ли видеть люди это приложение(нажимая на "приложения разработчика") если я под новым укажу другое имя.
2) Названия приложений. В IOS они ведь должны быть не длиннее примерно 15 символов, но Viber, например, в AppStore называется Viber Messenger: бла бла, а при скачке просто Viber. Вот где указывать имя в AppStore, а где в IOS

Всем большое спасибо)

Comment: А что за приложение, если не секрет ?

Comment: @kxxko, обзоры уличной еды в России. Там народ комментарии пишет, оценивает, говорит где траванулись и лучше не кушать.

Comment: Удачи Вам с этим =)

Comment: Кстати, если есть желание обсудить это и не только - можете оставить свой email :)

Comment: @kxxko andrewgurew123@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я знаю - на сегодня ограничение названия приложения увеличено до 30 символов, это во-первых, а во-вторых при публикации вы будете заполнять метаданные на приложение и там само-сабой получите ответы на свои вопросы. В любом случае эти данные можно редактировать и менять в дальнейшем. Насчет названия разработчика - не думаю, что это возможно - apple следит за тем, чтобы все всему соответствовало, меня, например, заставили поменять скриншоты на приложение, потому что в них на заднем плане было видно меню Finder на русском, а приложение на английском и без локализации - написали: "Вводите в заблуждение ..." :)

Comment: Спасибо, частично ответили на мой вопрос. 
Когда заполняешь данные о приложении там есть Name, я так понял этот имя приложения в AppStore, а в Xcode есть Display name - это уже имя в меню. Так ведь?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь - да (давненько публиковал под iOS :))

Answer (score 0):

Относительно имени приложения, которое будет видно в AppStore:

1. В проекте (PROJECT/Build Settings/Product name) задается как PRODUCT_DISPLAY_NAME;
2. В info.plist оно фигурирует под названием: Bundle display name;
3. Ссылка на info.plist присутствует в TARGETS/Build Settings/Packaging/
   где имя приложения фигурирует в используемых вами сборках, например adHoc,Debug,Distribution под Product Name.
4. Также имеется запись об имени приложения в TARGETS/Build Settings/User-Defined PRODUCT_DISPLAY_NAME;

Длина имени приложения увеличена до 30 символов.